# "Cannot Move App Not Enough Storage Space" Error Message

Tags: external-sd

I have a Huawei Y635 phone running Android version 4.4.4 with 1GB of RAM and 8GB phone storage. I bought an 8GB SD card to transfer some apps as the phone memory is nearly full. The SD card has 7.19GB of free space but when I try to move apps I get the error message stating there is not enough space. I have made the SD card the default storage location. The app I was trying to move was only 92.09MB. I have read some of the other posts but can't seem to get answer to this specific query. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the first time you have added a SD card ?.
Open Settings - Storage and check if you can see the the storage space details. If not ,you must Mount your SD card by a button there, after that you can move files or apps to SD card without error.

Another issue could be that your SD card was not recognised (always showing 0Mb) because android or user settings are wrong. Hopefully this helped you